# Which is better? In 1960 was founded the library of ... or In 1960 there was founded the library of...?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, british-english

Please, let me know if there is necessary any "there" in the next paragraph:

1. In 1960 was founded the library of...
2. In 1960 there was founded the library of...

I would rather use sentences like The library of... was founded in the 1960's, but for now I'm concerned in some instructions for the given cases (1) and (2).

Answer (score 2):

*With or without* 'there', both the sentences sound awkward to me. The better construction you already had thought about!

> The library of .... was founded in 1960 or (in the 60s)

If you want another style with the numbers ahead...

> It was in 1960 the library of... was founded

There could be other ways to write this as well.

Comment: It is not mistake to place the time phrase at the start of the sentence. The optimal position is determined by context and intended emphasis. One could be writing about all of the important things that happened in 1960, for instance. Or one could be especially interested in a particular period of time: "*In the early days of the civil war*, ... ".

Comment: "Founded", not "found". Corrected for you in Rev 2.

Comment: BUT if the time came first it would be more natural to say "In 1960 the library was founded". The noun would definitely come before the verb here.